# Could not cast value of type 'FIRTimestamp' to 'FIRTimestamp'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write some unit tests for some model objects I'm developing.  I'm seeing some strange unexpected behavior when getting Timestamps out of an dictionary [String:Any]. The timestamp is nil when trying to cast to a non-optional. But you can see in the print outputs that it's a timestamp.  Does anyone have any ideas?

The output of the two print statements is:

```
nil
Optional(<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1562802592 nanoseconds=1123>)
```

```
import XCTest
import Firebase

@testable import MyTarget

class UserTest: XCTestCase {

    var testDict:[String : Any]? = [:]

    var renewalDate:Timestamp = Timestamp(seconds: Int64(1562802592), nanoseconds: Int32(1123))

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        testDict = [
            "userId": "userId",
            "firstName": "J",
            "lastName" : "R",
            "email": "j@example.com",
            "renewalDate": renewalDate
        ]
    }

func testInit_ReturnsInstanceWhenRequiredPropertiesAreSpecificed() {
        let zUser = ZenUser(dictionary: testDict)
        XCTAssertNotNil(zenUser, "ZenUser should not be nil")
}
}
```

```
ZenUser : DocumentDeserializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any]?) {
        let t = dictionary?["renewalDate"] as? Timestamp
        print(t)
        print(dictionary?["renewalDate"])
        guard let userId = dictionary?["userId"] as? String,
            let firstName = dictionary?["firstName"] as? String,
            let renewalDate = dictionary?["renewalDate"] as? Timestamp,
            let lastName = dictionary?["lastName"] as? String else {
                print("Missing fields, returning nil")
                return nil
        }

...

}

protocol DocumentDeserializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]?)
}
```

Why is the timestamp nil when casting to non-optional?

Here are the versions I'm using.

```
Using Firebase (6.4.0)
Using FirebaseABTesting (3.0.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (6.0.3)
Using FirebaseAuth (6.2.0)
Using FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Using FirebaseCore (6.0.4)
Using FirebaseFirestore (1.4.1)
```

Comment: `ZUser` or `ZenUser`? Which one is it?

Comment: Zen sorry typo when shortening code sample.

Comment: It isn't an instance of `Timestamp` so the downcast fails.  The output indicates that it is an instance of `FIRTimestamp` - You can confirm this using the debugger or by changing the downcast to a forced downcast `as!` and see what the exception says.

Comment: It is a Timestamp object, my understanding is the prefix FIR is dropped in Swift.

I did a force downcast and this is what it get

```2019-09-12 22:10:15.736009-0700 [ Could not cast value of type 'FIRTimestamp' (0x12bb54450) to 'FIRTimestamp' (0x106d87d20).```

Makes no sense.

Comment: I should call out that the ZenUser init method only returns nil when running unit tests. It works fine in the app itself.

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Has this been resolved?

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Create the `Timestamp` in your app code rather than the test code. I needed a `Timestamp` from a `Date`, so I created this extension (in the app code) and use it in my tests.

`Date` extension (`Date+Timestamp.swift`):

```
import FirebaseFirestore

extension Date {
    
    var timestamp: Timestamp {
        Timestamp(date: self)
    }

    // add more extensions upon need
}
```

Add the `Date` extension to your app target(s), not to the test target.

Part of the test:

```
let data: [String: Any] = [
    Receipt.Keys.date.rawValue: Date().timestamp
]
```

This way the tested code can properly cast the object to a `Timestamp`.